# Magento admin custom form with multiple entry

Tags: magento-1.9, adminform, save, form-key

I have a custom form in Magento admin. When I submit the form with multiple click of the save button the multiple entry are inserted in my table, even if I have a form key.

```
if ($data = $this->getRequest()->getPost()) {       
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    $formKey = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey();             
    $request->setParam('form_key', $formKey);   
    $model = Mage::getModel('flpackage/packages');
    $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
    $oldPrice = '';
    if ($id) {
        $model->load($id);
        $oldPrice = $model->getData('package_price');                                                
    }
    Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setFormData($data);
    try {
        $model->setData($data);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $this->__($e->getMessage());
        $this->getCoreSession()->addError($e->getMessage());
        if($this->getRequest()->getParam('id')) {
            $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array('id' => $id));
        } else {
            $this->_redirect('*/*/edit');    
        }
        return ;
    }
    if($id) {
        $model->setId($id);  
    }
    $model->save();
}
```

Screen:
[image]

Kindly suggest your answer for solving this issue.

Answer (score 4):

You can create a function in one of your javascript files like this:

```
function savePackage(){
    disableElements('save');
    if (editForm.submit() == false){
        enableElements('save');
    }
    varienGlobalEvents.attachEventHandler('formValidateAjaxComplete', function (){
        enableElements('save');
    });
}
```

Then, in your `Edit.php` block for your entity add this line in the `_prepareLayout` method:

```
$this->_updateButton('save', 'onclick', 'savePackage()');
```

This is not a hack or something I came up with.
This is how it works for saving the product attributes in the core:

- https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Attribute/Edit.php#L69
- https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/product/attribute/js.phtml#L40

Comment: This is the cleanest answer because it does not override core functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Package Name has to be unique? If so, you could check before save, if item with the same name already exists:

```
$packageName = $this->getRequest()->getParam('package_name');
if ($model->load($packageName, 'package_name')->getId()) {
    $model->save();
}
```

Comment: This is only work for the particular module. due you have any other idea to avoid inserting the multiple entry when click the save button multiple time

Comment: i check with existing customer and newsletter module in magento admin panel.but the customer multitime form submit is working fine(i mean even i click the save button multitime the single entry only inserting) but the newsletter if i click the save button for creating template means the template are inserting multiple time.

Answer (score 0):

Well that was interesting bug in core Magento. Just do one line change this way.

1. Open file  /js/mage/adminhtml/form.js
2. Add below one line code just before form is submit.

   ```
           /*Multiple Entry Bug Fix Start*/
           document.getElementsByClassName("save")[0].disabled = true;
           /*Multiple Entry Bug Fix End*/
   ```

   Approx line 67 (Just after admin form validation success)

**This will fix all multiple entry bug in all Magento modules.**